# Unable to switch cards in cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener, cardlayout

I've been working on a program with multiple cards - a roleplaying character generator. I have four cards, the first being a menu card, and the other three each doing a different part of the character generation. However, I'm having issues with the menu card switching to different cards.

I want it to, when the user presses "New Character", to switch to the first character card, CardChar. The code as it stands is below:

```
public class mabGUI implements MouseListener {


final static String Menu = "Menu";
final static String CharCreation = "Character Creation";
final static String CharSkills = "Character Skills Screen";
final static String CharEquip = "Character Equipment";

private JPanel panel;

public void paneCreation(Container Pane) {

    JPanel cardMenu = new JPanel();
    JPanel cardChar = new JPanel();
    JPanel cardSkills = new JPanel();
    JPanel cardEquip = new JPanel();

    panel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    panel.add(cardMenu, Menu);
    cardMenu.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
    panel.add(cardChar, CharCreation);
    cardChar.setBackground(new Color(210, 100, 140));
    panel.add(cardSkills, CharSkills);
    panel.add(cardEquip, CharEquip);

    Pane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    //CardMenu
    cardMenu.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNew = new JButton("New Character");
    btnNew.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("beep");
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (panel.getLayout());
            cl.show(panel, "CharCreation");
        }
    });
    btnNew.setBounds(20, 20, 150, 30);
    cardMenu.add(btnNew);

}

public void initialise() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MBCharGen");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

    mabGUI MBCG = new mabGUI();
    MBCG.paneCreation(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have it set up so that the main class activates the initialise function, which then creates the required gui items.

I've tried declaring the card layout in the class, switching from show to setvisible, and had a look at the various card layout examples out there, and I'm getting nothing. The mouse listener event is working, because the button is returning "beep" each time it's pressed.

Any ideas what I'm screwing up? I'm pretty sure it's going to be something tiny I've missed, but I'm having difficulties seeing it.

Comment: not sure but , instead of "CharCreation" try CharCreation (the string variable)
TRY - MODIFY CODE TO : cl.show(panel, CharCreation);

Comment: +1 to the above comment, since you want to use the `Character Creation` String value not the variable name interpreted as `String`.